# How to modify a ListView item in Android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm starting learning Android and I want to know if there is some option in Android that let you modify each item or view (I don't know how it's named exactly, I mean each of the items from an ArrayList that you show in a ListView).

Well, I made a ListView that is going to show some books that were located in an ArrayList named "books".

I made a custom adapter that I associate to the ListView to show each item with the corresponding layout in the application. I also have a class "book" for each item that is going to be shown in the ListView.

Further, I made an Intent that I call from MainActivity with startForActivityResult(), that I process in Book class and that I return to MainActivity with all data of a book with the method setResult and got the information with onActivityResult() and the requestCode.

So I don't have any problem to add items to the ListView, just I have the problems if I want to modify some of the items (or views) that are located in the ListView (for example if I have title and author of a book, if I put some wrong information, I want have the option to change it).

I have that, in the same moment that you click on some of the items of the ListView, a new layout will be show to modify the information that it's wrong so I use the method setOnItemClickListener with onItemClick event on the custom adapter that I created before. Here it's where I call the new Intent to modify the wrong information with the method startActivityForResult().

I made the same as before to add a new item but, instead of add a new item with custom_adapter.addBook(title,author) I want to know if there is some option to made something like this: custom_adapter.modify(title,author) or custom_adapter.update(title,author), I mean, when you have modify all the items that were wrong of a book (for example an EditText that were "title") and you have all the information in the MainActivity class (because you returned it with setResult), how to put it again in the same item updating it in the custom_adapter and also in the ArrayList.

I searched it on the Internet but I didn't find anything.

I'm sorry if I have a poor English, but I expect that it can be understand.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Basically you remove or add items through the Adapter. I also post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem correctly - you could simply modify the `ArrayList` of type `Book` that is backing your `ArrayAdapter`.

So if you know what `Book` object you want to modify then you can simply make your changes to the `Book` object itself. As long as this `Book` is a reference to the same object that you originally added to the `ArrayList` you instantiated your `ArrayAdapter` with then you can then call `custom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the adapter to redraw its childviews with the new data.

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't explain myself properly. What I want to do it's, after I set all my items in the ListView, if I want to modify one of them, I make click on it and a new layout appears. In this layout will be 2 EditText with the Title and Author of our book with old info, when I change it and press the button "Submit" I regret this info to the MainActivity. I tried to use custom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but I don't know how to make an exactly reference to the item that I pressed so I have the info but I don't know how to update them into the   custom adapter both ArrayList. Thank you

Comment: Ah ok - have you tried passing the position of the selected item to the intent when starting the activity, and then returning the same position with the activity result. Then you modify the Book at the given position in the adapter. Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good code samples on the Internet but you have to understand the code for your purposes. So...here is a start, look at [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView). The code shows the use of ArrayAdapter with getView() method. And I hope it shows how to define the listeners, which you need.

How about that for a start?  Have fun...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all help you gave to me. I'm very pleased with you. :)

Finally, I just send the info with a Bundle when I started the Intent, also with the position. And after, I just used this position to set the new info to my items (in my case, books).

Again, thank you very much ;)